# Exit Dreamwever during development

Tags: codeigniter

Since yesterday, during my development I’m experiencing bailout or exit my dreamwever. I was wondering this because it was happen only for some php pages. I tried a lot of examined and I noticed that it may cause to the portion with the code below. I tried to remove all line with this code and it works fine. Is there any something wrong with this type of coding? Please help.

Thanks in advance

Tirso

Maybe this is the cause of errors. I tried to change all element option like this

```
 <option value=“ok”>test</option> and never experiencing exit. 

 <?php foreach ($arr_classification->result() as $row )
{
    print '<option value="'.$row->sf_classification_id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
}
```

?> 
here is the whole php page

```
 <div id="register">
<form action="<?php echo site_url('jobseeker/register/register_info') ?>" method="post">    
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Account Information</legend>
        <small class="note">Note that the email address will be the Login ID</small>
        <ul class="reg-info">
            <li><label><span class="required">* </span>Email</label><input name="email" type="text"></li>
            <li><label><span class="required">* </span>Password</label><input name="password" type="password"></li>
            <li><label><span class="required">* </span>Re-enter Password</label><input name="cfpassword" type="password"></li>
            <li><label><span class="required">* </span>First Name</label><input name="firstname" type="text"></li>
            <li><label><span class="required">* </span>Last Name</label><input name="lastname" type="text"></li>
            <li><label><span class="required">* </span>Date of Birth</label><input name="birthday" type="text" id="date-pick"></li>
         </ul>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Information</legend>    
        <ul class="reg-info">
            <li><label><span class="required">* </span>Contact Number</label><input name="c_number" type="text"></li>
            <li><label><span class="required">* </span>Mobile Number</label><input name="m_number" type="text"></li>
            <li><label><span class="required">* </span>Alternate Email</label><input name="alt_email" type="text"></li>
            <li><label><span class="required">* </span>Location</label>
                <select name="ci_location">
                    <option value="">--Any Location--</option>
                <?php foreach ($arr_location->result() as $row )
                    {
                        print '<option value="'.$row->sf_location_id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
                    }
                ?>                       
                </select>
            </li>
            <li><label><span class="required">* </span>Area</label>
                <select name="ci_area">
                    <option value="">--Any Area--</option>
                <?php foreach ($arr_area->result() as $row )
                    {
                        print '<option value="'.$row->sf_area_id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
                    }
                ?>                      
                </select>
            </li>                         
        </ul>    
    </fieldset>
    <div class="submit"><input name="" type="submit" class="submit-blue" value="Register"/></div>   
</form>
```

Comment: hi to all

base on my new examined if I remove the word "php" in "<?php" it was never exit. But I am just wondering why only inside <select> element.

Comment: Are you saying that the code makes Dreamweaver crash?

Comment: yes, bu now it's all fine. I just remove my php code inside select element instead move select element inside php code.

thanks

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged using something else than codeigniter? 'dreamweaver' perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a Dreamweaver error that crashes on dynamic scripts like PHP or ASP and not a cause of CodeIgniter.

There are couple of knowledgebase and discussions in Adobe stating crashes in different scenarios and different version.

Dreamweaver CS3 crashes after Daylight Savings Time ends

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402776.html

DW CS3 crashes on a simple code (by placing php script in `select` element)

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/120008

Dreamweaver crashes on start up (mostly referring to CS3 and CS4)

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/417116

Comment: hi rockacola

Thanks for your response and answer.

Tirso